# Adding capabilities to the windows platform in a cordova project

Tags: windows, cordova, capability

I want to add these 3 capabilities to my windows application.

- **internetClientServer**
- **privateNetworkClientServer**
- **internetClient**

Initially I tried to add the capabilities from here,
[image]
But every time I build the windows project. These capabilities get detached.

And also I tried adding them to the `package.windows.appxmanifest` file manually too.

Even tried to add the capabilities to the config file which is in the root directory.

Also tried to create a separate `plugin.xml` file and tried to call it from there. But no luck.

Comment: I want to add musicLibrary capability... how?